# String assigned in function disappears

Tags: c++

I got this Wolf class constructor:

```
     Wolf(int position[], World& world)
    : Animal(world)
{
    this->position[Y] = position[Y];
    this->position[X] = position[X];
    age = 0;
    strength = 9;
    this->world = world;
    this->species.assign("Wolf");
    world.setTabWorld(position[X], position[Y], this);
}
```

In the debugger I can see that "Wolf" is assigned to string species, but as soon as I get out of this constructor, this object's species empties. Interestingly age and strength is untouched, so why does the string species disappear?

Comment: More context please. What is species and where is it declared?

Comment: Do you have two `species` (one in `Wolf` and one in `Animal`) ?

Comment: Class Wolf inherited string species from class Animal, which inherited this string from class Organism, where it was declared

Comment: Are you sure it was not redeclared in any class in your hierarchy?

Comment: @drescherjm I am sure it is not

Comment: What does settabworld do to this?

Comment: @Mike It sets a pointer to newly created object in two-dimensional array of pointers, but I'm pretty sure that this is not the problem, as age and strength is set properly

Comment: You're going to need to post enough code for us to throw it in a compiler and reproduce the problem. This code fragment is not enough for us to find the problem. Indeed, the problem is likely not even in the code you have shown us.

Comment: @cdhowie [ideone link](http://ideone.com/oerEHN)

Comment: Is `species` a `std::string` or some other thing that doesn't copy the 'Wolf' string literal into newly allocated internal storage?

Comment: @hooman I copied your code and fixed the missing `stdafx.h` header error and [it seems to work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff13e392b2e482fd). But note that `World` does not follow the rule of three/five. I suggest using `std::vector<std::vector<Organism*>>` instead of managing your own memory.

Comment: @cdhowie Deleting `stdfx.h` helped for a while, but after few minutes it does not work again. In the meantime I have not done any changes.

Comment: Sounds like undefined behavior. When you build are you getting any warnings?

Comment: @drescherjm No, nothing

Comment: @hooman I suspect that the line `this->world = world;` could be related to your problem. This invokes the copy-assignment operator on the reference `this->world` but `world` is a reference to the same object, so you are copy-assigning an object to itself. This *shouldn't* cause any problems, however... I would suggest deleting `World`'s copy and move members to rule out that as a potential source of UB: `World(World const &) = delete; World(World &&) = delete; World & operator=(World const &) = delete; World & operator=(World &&) = delete;`